# Optimizing a non-operator bilinear product over a Hilbert space

Tags: linear-algebra, calculus-of-variations

Sorry to use bra-ket notation, but I studied Physics, not Math.

---

Consider a bilinear-product defined by

$\langle x'|F|x \rangle = \langle x'|F(x',x)|x \rangle = F(x',x)$

such that, in general,

$\langle u|F|v \rangle = \int \int \langle u|x'\rangle\langle x'|F|x\rangle \langle x|v\rangle dx'dx $

Note that $F$ is not necessarily an operator, and $F|v\rangle$ is not necessarily a vector, but $F$ is bilinear.

---

Given $|v\rangle$, what normalized vector $\langle u|$ will optimize (either minimize or maximize) 
$\langle u|F|v \rangle$?  (At the optimum, $F$ must be real.)

---

As a simple example, I'd like to find the $\langle u|$ (as a function of $|v\rangle$) that minimizes $\langle u | (x'-x)^2 | v \rangle$

Comment: Hi, welcome to MO. I think some definitions are needed - In which Hilbert space do $u,v$ "live"? When you say $F$ is not an operator, you mean that $F$ is not a linear operator? E.g., in your example, what is $(x'-x)^2 \ket{v}$ if not a vector?

Comment: @AmirSagiv: physicists will never tell you in which Hilbert space their vectors live.  I know this from long, bitter experience

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to answer this, although I'm not completely sure I understand the question.  First, since this is a math forum, I will try to explain to others in mathematical language what I think is being asked.

I think the Hilbert space here is $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, and $\langle u|$ and $|v\rangle$ are elements of this Hilbert space. We are given a "bilinear" (meaning sesquilinear) form on this Hilbert space, maybe not everywhere defined, which can be expressed as $\{u,v\} = \int\int u(x) F(x,y) \overline{v(y)}\, dxdy$ for some function $F(x,y)$. However, it is not a bounded form, so $\int F(x,y)\overline{v(y)}\, dy$, as a function of $x$, need not belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. The question is then, for given $F$ and $v$, to find a unit vector $u$ which maximizes or minimizes $\{u,v\}$.

The "simple example" where $F(x,y) = (x-y)^2$ helps to clarify what is being asked. For instance, if we take $v(y) = \cases{1&if $0 \leq y \leq 1$\cr 0&otherwise}$ then $\int F(x,y)\overline{v(y)}\, dy = x^2 - x + \frac{1}{3}$, which does not belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. So there is no optimizing unit vector --- taking $u(x) = \pm\cases{1&if $n \leq x \leq n+1$\cr 0&otherwise}$ for a given integer $n$ yields $\{u,v\} = \pm(n^2 + \frac{1}{6})$, which goes to $\pm\infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Maybe the most helpful answer I can give is that *if* $F|v\rangle$ is a vector, then normalizing this vector yields the unit vector $u$ which maximizes $\langle u|F|v\rangle$, and its negation is the unit vector which minimizes $\langle u|F|v\rangle$, but if $F|v\rangle$ is not a vector then an optimizing $u$ probably does not exist.

Probably I had better apologize in advance if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thank you.  This is all in line with my own thinking.

In general, there will be no unique normalized $\langle u|$ that optimizes $\langle u | F | v \rangle$

What I'm looking for is an equation that $\langle u |$ must satisfy when it is the optimum (similar to the Euler-Lagrange equation being satisfied by an optimizing function of a functional when an optimum exists)

If we look for U such that $|u\rangle = U|v\rangle$, then U is unitary, so $U=e^{iH}$ for hermitian H.  In the example $F = (x-y)^2$, I'm pretty sure $H = C\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ for some real C

Comment: I should add that I believe H to be related to F via something similar to the Legendre transform.  To get this, I make the substitution $(x+y)=q$ and $(x-y)=r$, and then I make some analogies between the Euler-Lagrange equations and dynamics on Hilbert space (unfortunately, I cannot fit those analogies into this comment)

Comment: Can you give me any example of $\langle u|$ and $|v\rangle$ for which $\langle u|$ mimizes $\langle u|(x-y)^2|v\rangle$? Besides the case where $(x-y)^2|v\rangle = 0$.

Comment: I'm actually going to sleep now.  I'll try to answer your question more fully when I get home from work tomorrow evening.  However, if $|v\rangle$ is a gaussian centered at x=0 (i.e. $\langle x | v \rangle \propto e^{-Cx^2}$ for some C) then I suspect the optimizing $|u\rangle$ will also be a gaussian centered at x=0. My reasoning is that my optimization problem (assuming I've formulated it correctly) can be used to define dynamics on a Hilbert space, and $F = (x-y)^2$ (again, assuming I've formulated the problem correctly) will give the same dynamics as the Lagrangian $L = \frac{dx^2}{dt^2}$.

Comment: As I said, I'm trying to find a way to generate dynamics on a Hilbert space from an optimization problem, similar to how variational calculus can be used to generate dynamics on the real numbers from an optimization problem.

Comment: I don't think that's true, though.  If $\langle y|v\rangle = e^{-y^2}$ then $\langle x|(x-y)^2|v\rangle = ax^2 + b$ for (easily computed) positive constants $a$ and $b$. This does not belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, so there will be unit vectors $\langle u|$ for which $\langle u|(x-y)^2|v\rangle$ is arbitrarily large or small.